# MySQL timestamp throwing incorrect datetime value on one specific datetime

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, laravel-8, php-carbon

I have unix timestamps associated with data I am getting from an API. These timestamps are being converted to a datetime via Carbon. I found one specific datetime value that keeps throwing errors:

```
UPDATE `revive_logs` SET `revivee_last_action_at` = '2018-03-11 02:12:33' WHERE `revive_logs`.`id` = 5129189
```

> Incorrect datetime value: '2018-03-11 02:12:33' for column 'revivee_last_action_at' at row 1

It makes no sense because if I switch the time for `2018-03-11 03:12:33` or `2018-03-11 01:12:33` it works fine. The error happens at that specific date, and hour only. If I change to other hours in that same day MySQL has no problem with it.

What am I doing wrong here? I cannot see anything incorrect about the datetime value. It's a valid date. Even phpMyAdmin lets me set this exact time in their date picker tool and it still throws the error there.

Comment: i guess its due to day saying time. Change the system timezone to the one that does not use DST and you should be fine.

Comment: Not reproduced. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5270b28503674d3e9819c15f9387ba6a Possible reason - there exists some incorrect unreadable char in the value. Try to re-type the whole literal, including quote chars. Try to debug: execute update as ```UPDATE `revive_logs` SET `revivee_last_action_at` = (@tmp := '2018-03-11 02:12:33') WHERE `revive_logs`.`id` = 5129189;``` then ```SELECT @tmp, HEX(@tmp);``` then investigate the output byte-by-byte.

Comment: I suspect @AqibJaved is correct, so check your time zone. For the US, March 11 is the date when DST "springs ahead". On that day there is no 2AM hour.  Time jumps straight from 1:59:59AM to 3:00AM. So '2018-03-11 02:12:33' isn't a valid date for that timezone.

Comment: Unix timestamps are seconds since January 1st 1970 UTC. "UTC" here is an important part of the definition, it implies that you should set your database and app.timezone config in laravel also in UTC to match and that's anyway the right way to make your app resilient to the various timezones the users could be in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the timezone is

- `Bermuda`
- `Canada`
- `Cuba`
- `Greenland`
- `Haiti`
- `Mexico`
- `Saint Pierre and Miquelon`
- `The Bahamas`
- `Turks and Caicos Islands`
- `United States`

then it is the switch hour between `Standard Time` and `Daylight Saving Time` (DST).

On 2018 it was scheduled to `Sunday, 11 March 2018` to move clocks from `2 AM` to `3 AM`.

So there was no time between `02:00:00` and `03:00:00`.

[Source](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2018.html)

Comment: I guess when people say dealing with times/dates is complicated they really aren't joking. In my case I am using UTC timezone which I assumed would not have the problem of having to deal with DST. However I wonder if the problem is because my database itself is set to my Canadian timezone (EST).